# MySQL::connect() database connection failed?

Tags: php, mysql

I have some PHP project?? when I install then its gives following error..?

```
Strict Standards: Static function SkaDate7Install_Step::is_completed() should not be abstract in C:\xampp\htdocs\SkaDate\install\index.php on line 29

Warning: SK_MySQL::connect() database connection failed in C:\xampp\htdocs\SkaDate\internals\API\MySQL.class.php on line 24
```

Why this error occure??

Please tell me.. I am new at PHP Platform...!! So, I dont know anything about PHP & MySql..

Comment: show your connection code

Comment: Sounds like you didn't enable the mysql libraries on php.ini

Comment: *"So, I dont know anything about PHP & MySql."* - that's why there are plenty of tutorials and manuals to read on Google, MySQL.com and PHP.net

Comment: Typical "I just got my driver's license, then bought a Dragster and an F1 racer". Now show me "how to...".

Comment: I am installing php project on localhost.. & when i install project then this error occur..??

Answer (score 0):

While installing did you give Database,username,password & host/ip? you need to also create that database on given hostname/ipaddress with the permission granted to chosen username & password.